# How to return the selected row from gridview row command?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I cannot figure out what's wrong with my code. I have looked at multiple similar posts, with no luck.
My code is returning the first row from the gridview. I want it to return the selected row. Can anybody see the problem?

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td class="grid-white-body-left"></td>
        <td class="grid-white-body-center">
            <asp:GridView ID="gvTradeCallOffList" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EmptyDataText="No Trade Call-Off(s) found."
                GridLines="Horizontal" SkinID="SimpleBlackWhite" OnRowCommand="gvTradeCallOffList__RowCommand">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="BookingID" HeaderText="Booking ID" SortExpression="BookingID"/>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="RegistrationID" HeaderText="Registration ID" SortExpression="RegistrationID" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="BookingDateTime" HeaderText="Current Booking DateTime" SortExpression="BookingDateTime" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="CreatedDate" HeaderText="CreateD DateTime" SortExpression="CreatedDate" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="TradeName" HeaderText="Trade Name" SortExpression="TradeName" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="PreferredFirstName" HeaderText="Preferred Contact First Name" SortExpression="PreferredFirstName" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="PreferredLastName" HeaderText="Preferred Contact Last Name" SortExpression="PreferredLastName" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Telephone" HeaderText="Telephone" SortExpression="Telephone" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Mobile" HeaderText="Mobile" SortExpression="Mobile" />
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Contacted?">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtNotes" Text='<%# Bind("Notes") %>' TextMode="MultiLine" Height="70px" Width="300px" runat="server">
                            </asp:TextBox>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Button ID="btnSaveNotes" Text="Save Notes" CommandName="SaveNotes" runat="server" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblSaveNotesSuccess" runat="server" Text="" EnableViewState="false"></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
        </td>
        <td class="grid-white-body-right"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="grid-white-footer-left-roundL"></td>
        <td class="grid-white-footer-center"></td>
        <td class="grid-white-footer-right-roundL"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</asp:Content>
```

Code Behind:

```
protected void gvTradeCallOffList__RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "SaveNotes")
        {
            int index;
            bool bIsConverted = int.TryParse(e.CommandArgument.ToString().Trim(), out index);
            GridViewRow selectedRow = gvTradeCallOffList.Rows[index];

            TextBox txtNotes = (TextBox)selectedRow.FindControl("txtNotes");
            string tradeCallOffListNotes = txtNotes.Text.Trim();

            int bookingID = Convert.ToInt32(selectedRow.Cells[0].Text);

            DataTable dt = new TradeBookingDAL().SaveTradeCallOffListNotes(bookingID, tradeCallOffListNotes);
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                string val = dt.Rows[0]["Notes"].ToString();
                txtNotes.Text = val;

                Label lblSaveNotesSuccess = (Label)selectedRow.FindControl("lblSaveNotesSuccess");
                lblSaveNotesSuccess.Text = "Notes saved successfully";
                lblSaveNotesSuccess.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
            }
            else
            {
                Label lblSaveNotesSuccess = (Label)selectedRow.FindControl("lblSaveNotesSuccess");
                lblSaveNotesSuccess.Text = "Notes not saved successfully";
                lblSaveNotesSuccess.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        new Util().LogError(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: did you try something like `int index = yourDGV.SelectedRows[0].Index;`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everybody for your help but I've figured out the answer.

Replaced these lines:

```
int index;
bool bIsConverted = int.TryParse(e.CommandArgument.ToString().Trim(), out index);
GridViewRow selectedRow = gvTradeCallOffList.Rows[index];
```

With this:

```
GridViewRow selectedRow = (GridViewRow)(((Button)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `dt.Rows[0]` will always give the first row as expected since you request the first item (0 index) in your `DataTable`.

1. You can get the selected row by the `SelectedRow` property of gridview. Then you can use the `DataItemIndex` property of this row to know what row it is in your underlying datatable. But since you are using the `rowcommand` event, this does not mean the row of the command is also the selected row.
2. You can bind in your rows to the `CommandArgument` and assign the index or primary key value and use this value in your `RowCommand` method like `e.CommandArgument`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it should be

```
int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
GridViewRow row = gvTradeCallOffList.Rows[index];
```

works for me in my Rowcommand